# Insert/Remove not working in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm facing a problem with **Entity Framework 6**. I have *People* Database and *PeopleEntities*. When I want to insert a new record (or delete one), the record is not added (or deleted) in the database.

This is my code:

```
PeopleEntities entities = new PeopleEntities();

Person person = new Person();
person.FirstName = "text here";
person.LastName = "text here";
person.Age = 20;

entities.Person.Add(person);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Note that getting the records like this: entities.Person.ToList(); is working.

Comment: are you getting an exception? how's the person object looks like?

Comment: No. I have no error in runtime. Person class has four properties: PersonId (Identity), FirstName, LastName and Logo (witch is optional it the database)

Comment: How do you know that nothing added/deleted? Try to dispose and recreate  dbcontext and check again.

Comment: I tried to recreate dbcontext but still not working. Note that after inserting the record and recreating dbcontext, I'm allowed to display the new record in console, in a foreach loop, BUT nothing happens in the database ..

Comment: the `SaveChanges` method returns an `int`. what's the result you're getting?

Comment: Strangely,  SaveChanges() returns 1, so it should work. But when I click "Show Table Data", there are no records...

Comment: what database are you using? what EF approach (code first, model first)?

Comment: .Mdf Database, ADO.NET Entity Data Model, Code First Approach

Comment: how's your `DbContext` class looks like? how's the `connection string` looks like?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qFDkwZ2R Note that the class was auto-generated from the database

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `Copy to output` property of the `mdf` file to `Do not copy` in solution explorer.
my guess is that it gets erased each time you run the application.

Comment: Try changing `|DataDirectory|` to something like c:\ in your connection string